# filter using Q object with dynamic from user?

Tags: django, django-q

In my views.py I have a method:

```
#......
def get_filter_result(self, customer_type, tag_selected):
        list_customer_filter=[]
        customers_filter = Customer.objects.filter(Q(type__name=customer_type),
                                                   Q(active=True),
                                                   Q(tag__id=tag_selected))

        for customer_filter in customers_filter:
                    customer_filter.list_authorize_sale_type = sale_type_selected(customer_filter.authorize_sale_type)
                    list_customer_filter.append(customer_filter)
        return list_customer_filter
```

**My case tag_selected is the checkbox values that user checked
I have a problems with tag_selected(is the list=1,2,3,...) that pass from my url

```
/?customer_type=TDO&tag=2 ===>filter okay
/?customer_type=TDO&tag=3 ===>filter okay
?customer_type=TDO&tag=2,3 ===>How Can I add And condition in filter?
```

for example

```
if len(tag_selected)==1:
      customers_filter = Customer.objects.filter(Q(type__name=customer_type),
                                                       Q(active=True),
                                                       Q(tag__id=tag_selected))
else:
    customers_filter = Customer.objects.filter(Q(type__name=customer_type),
                                                       Q(active=True),
                                                       Q(tag__id=tag_selected[0])
                                                       Q(tag__id=tag_selected[1])
                                                       Q(tag__id=tag_selected[2])
                                                       ...
                                                        )
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works for both single and multiple conditions:

```
idseq = request.POST['tag'].split(',')
tag_qs = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(tag__id=x) for x in idseq))
Customers.objects.filter(..., tag_qs)
```

Comment: global name 'operator' is not defined

Comment: okay for operator.
idseq = tag_selected.split(',')
print idseq #It display:[u'2', u'3']
tag_qs = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(tag__id=x) for x in idseq))
It raise an error.Thank for you help.:)
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,3'

Comment: Thankssssssssssssss  Ignacio Vazquez-Abran it works ,I fixed it ...

:)

Comment: For this you'll need `from functools import reduce, import operator`