# Search in Django and GET with multiple words

Tags: django, search, view, words

Could you tell me what should I use or where to look if I want to make something like this: When someone types "aaa bbb" (?t=aaa+bbb) in search field, it would only find those models, in which Title field is "aaa bbb", but not "aaa ccc bbb". How to change for example this code to make it find all titles, in which Titles is "aaa" or "bbb" word?

```
if 't' in request.GET:
    search = request.GET['t']

result = somemodel.objects.filter(Title__icontains = search).order_by('-pub_date')
```

Or in Title are "aaa" and "bbb" words, but not exatcly one after another? Should I change "icontains" to something else? Or make some loop to split "aaa bbb" into "aaa" and "bbb" if yes - how?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957240/filter-using-q-object-with-dynamic-from-user/1957263#1957263), but split on whitespace (`.split()`) and use the appropriate field in the `Q` objects.

Comment: search = request.GET['t'].split()
This don't work or maybe I don't know how to use it. If I put it, nothing can be found after typing something in search box.

Comment: Now it looks like this (obviously it doesn't work) - first line: search = request.GET['t'].split() ... and second: result = somemodel.objects.filter(Q(Title__icontains = search)|Q(Title__icontains = x) for in search).order_by('-pub_date') ... The error message is "'Q' object has no attribute 'split'", but I don't know if it all has valid syntax (don't mention about if this would even work:)

Comment: You missed the `reduce()` call.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now second line looks like this: result = pub.filter(Q(Nazwa__icontains = sth)|reduce(operator.or_, (Q(Nazwa__icontains = x) for x in sth))) - and error message is: 'str' object has no attribute 'or_' - I doubt that I write this line correctly, but I don't know, where is mistake (I defined earlier "pub" and "operator") and I this error lies in this piece of second line: ...sth)|reduce(operator.or_, (Q(Nazwa__icontains = x) for x in sth)))

Comment: You're using `operator` to store a string when it should instead be the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module in the stdlib.

Comment: I understand, but I have no idea where to look about putting operator in stdlib (I am googling for it now, but without success)

Comment: Understood. I put "import operator", deleted operator = '' and.. finally it works! Thanks a lot! :))