# Adding first_name and last_name in Django Search

Tags: django

I have the code below for a search. Supposing I have a posts from "John Doe". If I put "John" or "Doe" separately in the search I am able to get search results.

However if I put "John Doe" together I get 0 results. How must I change my code so that I can get both 'first_name' and 'last_name' together. In other words I want "John Doe" in search to show posts

```
class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(Postlist, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__username__iexact=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__iexact=query)|
                Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)


            )
        return queryset
```

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957240/filter-using-q-object-with-dynamic-from-user) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182041/search-in-django-and-get-with-multiple-words) question.

Comment: Another interesting [article](https://spapas.github.io/2016/09/12/django-split-query/)

Comment: awesome reading them now