# Using Django's Q to get search result from CBV's

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to implement a simple search feature in my CBV's ListView below is how my ListView looks like

```
class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
```

I would like to achieve something like this (Source: [Youtube video on how to add search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rk83AiKTDLY&list=PLKILtxhEt4-RT-GkrDkJDLuRPQfSK-6Yi&index=31))

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)|
            Q(user__username=query)|
            Q(body__icontains=query)

        )
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

but I guess I can't account for the SelectRelatedMixin. I am fine with using either. FBV or CBV as long as I can get the search working

I tried the code below.  I get NameError: name 'query' is not defined

```
class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Post    

    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(user__username=query) |
        Q(body__icontains=query)
    ).select_related('user', 'group')
```

Comment: What is SelectRelatedMixin? And what's wrong with the functional view, if it does what you want?

Comment: And why can't you do that with the functional view?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? We need more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function-based view, you can simply call `select_related()` on your queryset.

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query)|
    Q(user__username=query)|
    Q(body__icontains=query)
).select_related('user', 'group')
```

In the class-based view, you could override `get_queryset`:

```
class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(Postlist, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__username=query)|
                Q(body__icontains=query)
            )
        return queryset
```

Comment: Is this what you mean, If I do this I get NameError: name 'query' is not defined


class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Post    

    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(user__username=query) |
        Q(body__icontains=query)
    ).select_related('user', 'group')

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's impossible to read. The `posts = Post.objects.filter(...)` is for the function-based-view. If you are using a class based view, then override `get_queryset` like in my answer.

Comment: thanks that worked. also point taken on adding code in comments

Comment: do you think you could help me with a similar django question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588341/adding-first-name-and-last-name-in-django-search