# How to create a refine or advance search with individual fields in Django

Tags: django

I have made a search field in the navbar, Currently the search finds posts by title, username, first_name, last_name. A search with "title" could have 100 results and so on.

My current search in navbar which I want to keep

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="{% url 'posts:all' %}">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
      </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I now want to create a refined search page(A new Page). In that page there will be 4 separate search fields, 
Example:

Search Posts by Title: __Search box_____

Search Posts by username __Search box____

Search Posts by  first_name __Search box____

Search Posts by  last_name __Search box____

This is how the views look for all fields combined .

```
class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
model = Post
select_related = ('user', 'group')
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(Postlist, self).get_queryset()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)|
            Q(user__username__iexact=query)|
            Q(user__first_name__iexact=query)|
            Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

        )
    return queryset
```

I am sorry if the question is too basic I am a beginner with django. How do I go about doing this. Will there be 4 forms with different names. example instead of name="q", Will I have form name="a", form name="b",form name="c", etc. Also how will the views look

Comment: in name="q", what is name  you mean?

Comment: are you asking whether there will be 4 forms, where each form will have one field?

Comment: I mean the name of the form. Yes that is exactly what I am asking will there be 4 forms each with a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That new page your talking about could have a single HTML form with 4 HTML input fields, each with its own `name` attribute (for example: `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3` and `field_4`).

Your view could look like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()

    final_q = Q()  # empty Q that will be OR'ed together with the other statements
    if len(self.request.GET.get('field_1', '')) > 0:
        final_q |= Q(title__icontains=self.request.GET['field_1'])
    if len(self.request.GET.get('field_2', '')) > 0:
        final_q |= Q(user__username__iexact=self.request.GET['field_2'])
    if len(self.request.GET.get('field_3', '')) > 0:
        final_q |= Q(user__first_name__iexact=self.request.GET['field_3'])
    if len(self.request.GET.get('field_4', '')) > 0:
        final_q |= Q(user__last_name__iexact=self.request.GET['field_4'])

    # apply Q to queryset
    qs = qs.filter(final_q)

    return qs
```

Comment: If I replace my code with this code it gives "all" the results as is no matter what I type.

Comment: Changed the `if` statements in my answer. Does this version work?

Comment: checking to now

Comment: I think I maybe doing something wrong I am replacing your code with my code the one which is currently handling my navbar search. Will I need to make 2 separate querysets 1 for the general navbar search and  1 for the advance search page

Comment: Yes, you will need different methods because my code looks for 4 different `name` attributes (4 different form input fields) while your code used only 1 input field.

Comment: Or you could add some more `if` statements to the code to account for both cases, but that makes the logic more complex and harder to understand.

Comment: awesome that works. Could you look into a similar question I have 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588341/adding-first-name-and-last-name-in-django-search

Answer (score 1):

You can have 4 search fields in one form, in view function you can check the value of each field and query accordingly.

you can do `print(request.GET)` to see all field names and then access each field like:

```
request.GET['field1']
```