# How to create a filter from request.GET parameters?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [filter using Q object with dynamic from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957240/filter-using-q-object-with-dynamic-from-user)

I am working on a filter feature in my app. I send a comma separated string via jquery to Django (within jquery I replace the space with a +, so that it can be sent over the wire).

```
/?ajax&sales_item=t2,+t1
```

Now in the view when I retrieve the GET parameters, I can see Django has already replaced the + with a space, which is great. Then I split the keywords by comma and strip the whitespace.

```
sales_item_raw = request.GET['sales_item']
sales_item_keywords = sales_item_raw.split(',')
```

I need first to check if the given names even exist as sales item. I have to use a `icontains`, hence `sales_items` can be more than one item.

```
for item in sales_item_keywords:
        sales_items = profile.company.salesitem_set.filter(item_description__icontains=item.strip())
```

Last but not least the queryset is used to filter deals for the given sales_items:

```
deals_queryset = deals_queryset.filter(sales_item__in=sales_items)
```

If the user filters for only one keyword that would work fine, however if there are two keywords the `sales_items` will be obviously overwritten in each loop iteration.

What is the most performant way to solve this? Shall I just append the content of `sales_items`in each iteration to a list outside the loop? And eventually send the new list to the final `deals_queryset.filter`?

I am not sure if this is a good way to solve this...

Comment: "I send a comma separated string via jquery to Django (within jquery I replace the space with a +, so that it can be sent over the wire)." There's no need; Django has no problem dealing with multiple GET parameters [with the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4359238/20862).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It is not about multiple GET Parameters, if I didn't replace whitespace with a +, I would get only the first parameter passed in. `/?ajax&sales_item=t2,`  The whitespace cuts off the second argument. At least this is what is happening on my serverrun.

Comment: `/?ajax&sales_item=t2&sales_item=t1`

Comment: ahh now I understand where my mistake was. Thank you again for your help. :)

Comment: If somebody would like to come up with somthing more generic it is worth having look at django's admin filters as source of inspiration https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/filters.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Django's [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object to create "or" logic in your filter.

```
# create a chain of Qs, one for each item, and "or" them together 
q_filters = Q(item_description__icontains=sales_item_keywords[0].strip())
for item in sales_item_keywords[1:]:
    q_filters = q_filters | Q(item_description__icontains=item.strip())   

# do a single filter with the chained Qs
profile.company.salesitem_set.filter(q_filters)
```

This is ugly code, as I'm not sure how to handle the initial Q elegantly, as I'm not sure what is an "empty" Q to which you can chain all other Qs, including the first one. (I'm guessing you could use `Q(pk=pk)` but that's ugly in a different way.)

EDIT: Ignacio's link above shows the way, i.e.

```
q_filters = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(item_description__icontains=item.strip()) for item in sales_items_keywords))
profile.company.salesitem_set.filter(q_filters)
```

Comment: `reduce()` is smart enough to... oh. You're not using `reduce()`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- :-) I was adding that approach in, based on your other answer, at the same time you noticed the lack of `reduce()`.

Comment: Ahh this is excellent. Thank you both so much. :) It works now very nicely.